# EXCEL: Automating spreadsheet data input

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently doing some data entry for a spreadsheet which contains hundreds on entries and want to automate the process, I have a good idea of what I want it to do but have little experience with Excel or VBA.

The idea behind it is that I have a code in one column and in the next column there is another code which is unique to the value in the former column. To give an example:

[image: Excel Example 1]

So for every cell that contains 123, the column next to it will be "ABC".

The sort of solution I would like is a macro that will work its way down Column A, storing the value of each cell (or something of that effect) and then working its way down to check for values that match that stored one. If a match is found, the macro will then copy the code from column B, the cell that is next to the stored cell and copy it into the cell in column B, next to the match.

EXAMPLE:

[image: Excel Example 2]

It will store the "123" value in A, work its way down Column A to find other cells matching "123" and when it finds them copy  "ABC" into the column B cells next to the matches.

Hope this is easy to understand and someone can help me with coming up with a solution, would make this whole process alot easier as the spreadsheet is growing by the day and manual input is taking far to much time

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this macro a try:

```
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
    Dim rA As Range
    Dim rB As Range
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range
    Dim N As Long
    Dim va As Variant
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rA = Range("A1:A" & N)
    Set rB = rA.Offset(0, 1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    If rB Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In rB
        va = r.Offset(0, -1).Value
        For Each rr In rA
            If rr.Value = va And rr.Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then
                r.Value = rr.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Next rr
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah looks that is working! Thanks, saved me from hours of work and my boss chewing my head off.